# I can't make query in django to filter out posts from those users that the currently logged in user is following

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-models, erd

I am working on a Django project where a user can follow other users, create posts and so on just like Twitter or Instagram. However, I have a problem writing queries in views.py to filter out all the posts from the people that currently logged in user is following. Here, I am sharing my views.py function, model, template and corresponding ER diagram.

> views.py

```
def followerspost(request):
  user = request.user
  profile = Profile.objects.filter(user = user)
  followings = user.profile.followings.all()
  for following in followings:
    posts = NewPost.objects.filter(user = following)

  return render(request,"network/following.html",{
    "user" : user,
    "profile" : profile,
    "followings" : followings,
    "posts" : posts,
  })
```

> models.py

```
class NewPost(models.Model):
  user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
  post = models.TextField()
  timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)

  def __str__(self):
    return f"{self.post}"

class Profile(models.Model):
  user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
  picture = models.ImageField(blank=True,null=True,upload_to="images/")
  followers = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank=True, related_name="followers")
  followings = models.ManyToManyField(User,blank = True, related_name="followings")
```

I have designed my database according to the following ER diagram.
[image]

> urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
  path("profile/<int:id>/following/addfollower",views.followersPeople,name="addfollower"),
path("profile/<int:id>/following/removefollower",views.followersRemove,name="removefollower"),
path("following",views.followerspost,name="following"),]+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root= settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

> following.html

```html
<h1>All Posts</h1>
        
        <div id="posts" class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
                {% for posts in posts %}
                    <ul>
                         <li class="card"> 
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <h5 class="card-title"><a style="text-decoration: none;" href="{% url 'profile' posts.user.id %}">{{ posts.user }}</a></h5> 
                                <h6 class="card-subtitle text-muted">{{ posts.timestamp }}</h6>
                                <h3 class="card-text">{{ posts.post }}</h3>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>   
                {% empty %}
                    <h6>No post availabel </h6>
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
            
        </div>
```

But when I visit the following.html, it displays posts from only one user (Followed by the currently logged in user) and doesn't display any posts from others. What should I do now?

Comment: While fetching posts you are assigning to posts variable everytime. So you are getting the latest value.  Try putting them in a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
def followerspost(request):
  user = request.user
  profile = Profile.objects.filter(user = user)
  followings = user.profile.followings.all()
  posts = NewPost.objects.filter(user__in= followings) #new

  return render(request,"network/following.html",{
    "user" : user,
    "profile" : profile,
    "followings" : followings,
    "posts" : posts,
  })
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  for following in followings:
    posts = NewPost.objects.filter(user = following)
```

this is assigning value to posts variable every time, so you will get only last following's posts.

just do something like this and remove the loop

```
posts = NewPost.objects.filter(user__in = followings)
```